# synchronized my app with zune players in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, mediaelement, audio-player

I want to create a media player that is synchronized with zune in windows phone 7. Meaning that if the song is playing in Zune is also playing in my app. My app also take the songs library from Zune.
In other word, it's identical to Zune, except it's control through my app...
The reason I want to do this is to improve and add some other function to the current music player in windows phone 7. I have read [How to: Integrate with the Music and Videos Hub for Windows Phone:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769558%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

and this:

```
[http://mobile.dzone.com/news/gotchas-when-integrating-music?mz=27249-windowsphone7][2]
```

But it's not so clear and very limited what I can do.
Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance!

It could work this way, the actual player is Zune, all my App does is provide user control for Zune music player throught my app.

Answer (score 1):

And if I told you that you couldn't? Zune isn't a streaming service, so while you could probably get the current playing song of Zune over the network, you wouldn't get wireless sync of the music, and you would have to match it to the phone's media library based on the name, as there's no global identifier for any songs.

It seems well strange to want to play the song on **both** platforms at the same time.

Comment: It's one platfroms but was presented in 2 different apps, is this possible?

Comment: how about a simple music player that get all music library from zune? Thanks you

Comment: You cannot sync music **FROM** the phone. You can only sync it **TO** the phone (using Zune). And you can sync your entire library from Zune with a single click (ctrl+a to mark items, then right-click "Sync with WP7")